# Adding labels and icons on google maps markers

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I add labels to my two markers so that when you click on the marker it shows you more details about it and also how can I change the icon of the "Access Point 2" to a different marker

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.322402,31.142249),
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map-default'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatlng
        }),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "We are here!"
        });

    var accessPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.315402,31.123924),
        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: accessPoint1,
            map: map,
            title: "Access Point 1"
        }); 

    var accessPoint2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.316700,31.138043),
        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: accessPoint2,
            map: map,
            title: "Access Point 2"
        }); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#google-map-default {
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="google-map-default"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

the code above is in a file called maps.mini.js which is currently working fine. I just need to make modifications on it as specified above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a probably more robust and extendable solution that makes use of an array holding your locations (markers), and a single InfoWindow object. With this, you can add as many locations as you need without having to duplicate the rest of the code...

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.322402, 31.142249);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "We are here!"
  });

  var locations = [

    [new google.maps.LatLng(-26.315402, 31.123924), 'Access Point 1', 'Custom text 1'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(-26.316700, 31.138043), 'Access Point 2', 'Custom text 2']
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[i][0],
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][1]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }

    })(marker, i));
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your marker1 you can

```
    var my_contentString1 = 'my text content 1... ' ;

    var my_infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: my_contentString1
    });

    var accessPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.315402,31.123924),
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: accessPoint1,
        map: map,
        title: "Access Point 1"
    });

    marker1.addListener('click', function() {
      my_infowindow1.open(map, marker);
    });
```

do the same for marker2

Comment: would you mind adding that modification onto my code and sharing the complete code. Forgive me I'm still new to this

Comment: I do not like your comment ... this is not a free service of writing code

Comment: It should be quite easy for you to integrate this to your code with a little bit of thinking. On the given answer though, I would avoid creating a separate InfoWindow object for each marker. Not a big issue with 2 markers, but if you have 2000, then it might be another story.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way which worked so well for me

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var locations = [
       ['ap7', -26.303139, 31.093508, 7],
       ['ap6', -26.322402, 31.142249, 6],
       ['ap5', -26.316700, 31.138043, 5],
       ['ap4', -26.315402, 31.123924, 4],
       ['ap3', -26.329244, 31.150478, 3],
       ['ap2', -26.309525, 31.134632, 2],
       ['ap1', -26.289923, 31.140195, 1]
     ];

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 14,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-26.309525, 31.134632),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     var marker, i;

     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map
       });

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
         return function() {
           infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
       })(marker, i));
     }
 </script>
```